# How to keep columns based on a given row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here how the datalooks like in `df` dataframe:

```
        A   B   C   D
0.js    2   1   1  -1
1.js    3  -5   1  -4
total   5  -4   2  -5
```

And I would get new dataframe `df1`:

```
        A     C
0.js    2     1
1.js    3     1
total   5     2
```

So basically it should look like this:
`df1 = df[df["total"] > 0]` 
but it should filter on row instead of column and I can't figure it out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, loc with boolean indexing or reindex:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns[(df.loc['total'] > 0)]]
```

OR

```
df.reindex(df.columns[(df.loc['total'] > 0)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
       A  C
0.js   2  1
1.js   3  1
total  5  2
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `.loc[:, column_mask]` i.e.

```
In [11]: df.loc[:, df.sum() > 0]
Out[11]:
       A  C
total  5  2

# or

In [12]: df.loc[:, df.iloc[0] > 0]
Out[12]:
       A  C
total  5  2
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to set negative values to `NaN` and then [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) setting `axis = 1`:

```
df.where(df.gt(0)).dropna(axis=1)

       A  C
total  5  2
```